# Why did the U.S. veto the UN ceasefire resolution?

Tags: united-states, united-nations, 2023-israel-hamas-war, veto, unsc

On Wednesday, December 6, 2023, the United Nations Secretary-General Antonio Guterres invoked Article 99 of the U.N Charter on the situation in Gaza.

> Article 99 allows the secretary-general to “bring to the attention of the Security Council any matter which in his opinion may threaten the maintenance of international peace and security”

The invocation seems to be in line with the unfolding events in the middle east region.

- The humanitarian situation in Gaza is dire and worsening by the minute
- The West Bank is agitating with violence
- Iran-backed militants in Iraq are repeatedly attacking U.S. forces
- Iran-backed Houthi in Yemen are attacking Israel-linked ships in the Red Sea and firing ballistic missiles at Israel
- Hezbollah is attacking Israeli military sites and soldiers in the north of Israel daily.

Apparently, the region is slowly drifting into a regional war which can rapidly escalate to World War 3! The U.S. has repeatedly expressed that it doesn't wish to see the conflict in Gaza expand to a regional conflict, yet it vetoes the UN attempt at a ceasefire resolution.

The longer the war in Gaza endures, the more there is a chance a regional war could break out, so why did the U.S. neutralize the UN ceasefire resolution? Does that not contradict its publicly articulated intentions?

Comment: That World War 3! thingy seems strongly speculative in nature.  Which reasonable and influential individuals or bodies have been making that claim?  Can we get a citation?  Otherwise, yes, good question and likely on many people's mind.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica A china expert did. check out the this Fox  Business
YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-VvN0Im6ro

Comment: LOL. If a had a dime every time Fox News invited some "expert" on China. The only thing that qualifies someone as such there if they say that China is the root all evil. Which in that case they did say, i.e. that China is behind the Oct 7 attack. About par for the course given the affiliation of the source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatestone_Institute

Comment: There seems to be a lot of misunderstandings about what a ceasefire is and what they accomplish.  A ceasefire does not end the conflict, it is a temporary suspension of the violence. Of all of the listed points, only one, the first one, would be influenced by a ceasefire. Additionally, ceasefires typically have asymmetric influence to each participant of the conflict. If the call for a ceasefire does not include a benefit to both sides, it is essentially a call for support of one side.

Comment: @DavidS: I'm reminded of The Babylon Bee's recent headline "Hamas clarifies they only want Israel to cease fire".  It's satirical, but it works *because* a huge segment of the American population has that view of the ceasefire proposal.

Comment: Voting not to close - This question can be factually answered (I don't see what extra "details" this question needs to be clearer). The only improvement it needs is to add references. Those who are voting to close, please provide specific feedback, as what may be "blindly obvious" to you certainly isn't to the rest of us.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The UN Security Council and especially the veto powers used there are mostly a geo-policital platform and whatever the topic of the day is is mostly an afterthought.

During the Cold War, it was pretty much protocol for the USSR to veto anything the USA wanted and vice versa.

The US has used its [veto on dozens of past resolutions against Israel](https://www.un.org/depts/dhl/resguide/scact_veto_table_en.htm). This is part of how the US expresses its political support for Israel. This veto is simply a continuation of what the US has always done. It has nothing to do with this particular resolution or its contents, and if the US feared an escalation of the conflict, it would use its direct influence on Israel rather than supporting a UN resolution.

Comment: The US did not block (i.e. abstained on) a UNSC resolution that used softer language in re Israel a few weeks ago.  That one called for "“urgent and extended humanitarian pauses and corridors” in Gaza for “a sufficient number of days” to allow full, rapid, safe and unhindered access for UN agencies and partners". https://news.un.org/en/story/2023/11/1143632  So wording does matter in this case. The US did block like 3 other USNC attempts (generally advanced by Russia) to call for a permanent ceasefire.

Comment: @Fizz I agree that wording matters. The word "ceasefire" specifically has a defined meaning, unlike "pause".

Comment: The first two paragraphs are incorrect or unuseful. First, The UNSC is by definition a "geo-political platform", so it's meaningless to mention that as a reason for voting this way or that. It is also not true that the topic of the day is an afterthought, and very serious and grave topics with significant consequences are brought before it and discussed - after and during taking up a lot of the attention of many world powers. An example is wars which some UNSC members are involved in. /...

Comment: ... finally, and most importantly - this is not a "USSR vs USA" matter, nor "Russia vs USA", nor "China vs USA" etc. The proposal was supported universally (Britain, a very close US ally did not put itself in opposition to the US and just abstained).

Answer (score 43):

Well, we can read what the U.S [representative said the UN](https://news.un.org/en/story/2023/12/1144562):

> The US engaged in good faith on the text, said Deputy Permanent Representative Robert A. Wood, that would increase opportunities for hostage release and more aid to reach Gaza.
>
> “Unfortunately, nearly all of our recommendations were ignored” leading to an “imbalanced resolution that was divorced from reality that would not move the needle forward on the ground in any concrete way. And so, we regretfully could not support it."
>
> He said the US still could not understand why the resolution’s authors declined to include language condemning “Hamas’s horrific terrorist attack” on Israel, of 7 October.
>
> It killed people from a range of nationalities, subjecting many to “obscene sexual violence.”
>
> He said he had explained earlier in the day why an unconditional ceasefire would simply be “dangerous” and leave Hamas in place, able to attack again.
>
> It was “a recipe for disaster for Israel, for Palestinians and for the entire region”.
>
> Any ceasefire leaving Hamas in control would also deny Palestinians the chance to build something better for themselves, he added.

Moreover, the reasoning suggested in the OP that "the more the war in Gaza endures, the more there is a chance a regional war could break out" is not so obvious as it seems. Alternative view could say that if Israel stops now, the chances for WW3 would increase dramatically — it won't happen tomorrow, but probably in 2-3 years. As it would increase the likelihood that other factors would also try like Hamas to exterminate the Jews. In order to avoid war, U.S should show they are ready for war and are not afraid of it.

Comment: TLDR: you could emphasize the last sentence in the quote. The US agrees with the fundamental goal of Swords of Iron op: to remove Hamas from power. Calling for more than short ceasefires for aid delivery and/or for hostage releases is not in the US vision.

Comment: I'm not sure how you remove Hamas from power and it begins to look like Russian "denazification and demilitarization" where the objectives are either fake or completely unclear.

Comment: @alamar - I would not go quite that far—it's obvious that Israel does want to get rid of Hamas, if only out of self-interest, whereas Russia's commitment to getting rid of neo-Nazis is very questionable. But what is true is that there is clearly some motivation of revenge involved there, perhaps combined with a desire to acquire more territory, which is probably more important to Israel than the goal of getting rid of Hamas (which the war may even be counterproductive in, as I have previously suggested).

Comment: @Obie2.0 Hamas is people. I'm not sure how Israel can get rid of all those people. By running 2M population through filtration camps, perhaps?

Comment: @alamar - Practically, Israel can only (almost) get rid of Hamas by killing a disproportionate number of unarmed non-Hamas Palestinians as well, which is what they seem to be doing. Of course, it seems very unlikely that the lives saved by (more or less) eliminating Hamas could possibly make up for all those lost in the process, and some other group will likely arise anyway, with even more cause for resentment now.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I'm not even sure why Hamas would not resurface. ISIS was mostly Baath officers who survived Iraq war and had nothing to do.

Comment: _"try like Hamas to exterminate the Jews"_ - Hamas did not try to "exterminate the Jews" (unless you believe that terrorism == ethnic cleansing). On the other hand, Israel's actions have been widely described as genocidal by the [UN](https://www.ohchr.org/en/press-releases/2023/11/gaza-un-experts-call-international-community-prevent-genocide-against) and by [many genocide scholars, including Israeli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWGGjLZNuyg).

Comment: @alamar: for now it's the fighting age males that didn't flee [it seems](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67659296) that are getting "filtrated". The rest are probably a more negligible quantity, in the short run at least.

Comment: @Eyeofpie  One can easily argue that their latest attack was not expected to "exterminate the Jews" but that (or similar words) have been used many, many times by Hamas.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Given Netanyahu's previous comments about wanting Hamas to control Gaza (because having more militant Palestinians in power solidifies support for the Right in Israel, whilst having more moderate Palestinians in power would see people shift to the Left) it's not as obvious as you may think that the Israeli _government_ wants to get rid of Hamas (although it certainly is that the populace at large does, it generally being a safe bet that most people don't want unfriendly militants at their doorstep)

Comment: @Tristan - I believe that Netanyahu and some other politicians might have wanted a threatening Hamas in the Gaza Strip that he could use to menace people into supporting his preferred policies (Jewish nation-state and so forth). The question is how many of those members want a Hamas that might have a reasonable chance of killing them in a massive attack. Perhaps they want a substantially reduced Hamas, enough to still be a useful bogeyman, but not enough to pose a plausible threat to their own safety.

Answer (score 17):

Since the Q suggests WW3 and what not, I'll just add this bit from a Nov 14 [presser](https://www.defense.gov/News/News-Stories/Article/Article/3588803/pentagon-official-says-deterrence-in-middle-east-is-working/) of the Pentagon.

> Deterrence in the Middle East is working, Deputy Pentagon Press Secretary Sabrina Singh said today.

And yeah, the US says that's [because](https://www.voanews.com/a/nearly-60-attacks-on-us-forces-in-iraq-and-syria-/7355551.html) they are striking back.

> “Is deterrence working? We feel that it is," said Pentagon Deputy Press Secretary Sabrina Singh. "We have not seen this war spread into a wider regional conflict. The strikes that we are taking is to signal and to message very strongly to Iran and their affiliated groups to stop. That is the purpose of those strikes.”
>
> "I think we are being very deliberate on how and when we conduct our strikes against these groups," she said. "And I think that Iran is certainly seeing that message.”

Comment: "_Since the Q suggests WW3 and what not..._". Do you disagree that things are headed towards another world war? The Gaza war has destabilized the entire region.

Comment: @machine_1: You have to make up your mind if you're really asking about what the US says or you're merely using this Q to soapbox. In re the latter: my personal opinion is that WW3 would not start from the Middle East unless Russia somehow sees Iran as indispensable and intervenes on its behalf. Which seems pretty unlikely to me, but I have no more a of Putin mind reading device than you have. (Thus far Iran hasn't really proven it sees Hamas as indispensable either, I might add.)

Comment: For some Iranian statements on the latter see https://www.ft.com/content/e296eb62-cd36-4945-80c2-1ca3a6b79259 At best, they hope Israel will be stuck in a protracted guerilla war in Gaza.

Comment: @machine_1"World wars" were global wars that involved all of the world's super powers. Do you think China and the rest of NATO will be involved? A regional war != world war.

Comment: There are absolutely ties between the Russia v Ukraine conflict and the middle east. Not cutting oil production props up sanctioned Russia, and there are articles on credible news sites about Iran supplying drones and missiles.

Comment: Hamas benefits from the Russia-Ukraine war, because European countries are funding Qatar (and therefore Hamas) where they previously funded Russia.

Comment: Funny, I don't think your last bracketed sentence is true: The OP asked "why **did** the U.S. neutralize the UN ceasefire resolution", not "what did they *say*"; the OP actually made that distinction explicit by asking "does that not contradict its **publicly articulated** intentions?"! Therefore, here is *my* question: Do you think that the public statements reflect the true reasons?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: do you think that's an appropriate Q for SX?  https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3457/18373

Comment: @Fizz  I didn't ask that as a "Q"; but you imply it because you answer the question "why did they" with "they said". So I'm asking you specifically for a clarification: Do you think that your answer is an answer to the OP's question? I'm asking without prejudice; I have no clue.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: no, I mean do you think that asking whether the US is lying about the WW3 being about to start in Gaza is an appropriate Q for P.SE? Because that's the reading you give to the original Q. Which has 3 close votes BTW.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: To wit: the way you read the original Q seem to be "why is the US lying about WW3, which is about to start due to the situation in Gaza?" It seems to me that given that reading the Q is eminently closeable. But the OP managed to muddy/combine that with their Q on what the US *said* about their UNSC vote. Which is why I linked to the older meta-Q about muddy Qs like this.

Comment: @Fizz My meta opinions appear to be far removed from the meta opinions of the moderators. I generally think that the more undisputed a political fact is (parliament procedures etc.), the more trivial they are. Everybody can google those. Politics is the institutional resolution of conflicting interests. Yes, the institutions are important; but the interests are at least as important. Without understanding the motives of the actors you cannot understand their actions. With a good answer, previously inexplicable events make sense. (ctd.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: BTW, I see you've not left any comments under the top voted answer. Do you agree that if Hamas is *not* defeated now, WW3 could start in a few years? That's what that answer is saying.

Comment: @Fizz (ctd.) But these interests are often not in the open and can only be inferred; their discussion inevitably contains an element of opinion. There is a sweet spot on that spectrum between trivial procedure and conspiracy theory. It is where there are factual *indications* from which to infer underlying interests. That may be physical things like access to resources, previous conflicts, the always eminent *cui bono.* Behavior may also be an indicator. Statements, of course, can be. (ctd.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Unfortunately, I see this trend more and more often in Qs & As here. People post seemingly reasonable/objective questions and answers peppered with opinions that are anything but.

Comment: (ctd.) The best questions and answers, in my opinion, are fueled by an opinion or interest but are genuine attempts to understand something puzzling, or to seek confirmation for an assumption, or to obtain new angles on a problem. They are not unnecessarily inflammatory, and the poster should be open to other opinions. Those could be very good questions and answers. Most interesting questions concern conflicts which tend to evoke strong emotions (because people die etc.). But the guidelines and moderation do (I think: too) severely restrict such Q&A because such debates tend to derail quickly.

Comment: @Fizz Regarding "is WW3 more likely with or without Hamas": I don't have a clear opinion on that. I can see the perceived long-term benefits of eradicating Hamas, even if I wholeheartedly disagree (each killed innocent civilian begets an entire generation of orphans or bereft parents full of hatred). On the other hand: The short-term possibility that the conflict first escalates into a regional war between nations and then further into a world war is obvious. Therefore, I didn't feel I needed to vote or comment on that answer.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Ok, so I don't see why you expect me, unlike the OP and the top-voted answer to state my opinion on whether defeating Hamas now is useful or counterproductive in stopping WW3 now or later.

Comment: @Fizz I don't expect you to do anything except remove the last sentence which is wrong. The question simply is not "what does the US say".

Answer (score 9):

Your approaching WW3 argument for making a ceasefire doesn't hold up - first off, why does this seem so close to WW3? Its basically Israel, Hamas, Hezbollah, and Iran by proxy - hardly world powers. But besides for that, the Russia-Ukraine war is much, much, much, much closer to being WW3 - Putin clearly said that the US giving certain types of weapons to Ukraine would be considered an act of war against Russia. However, there is no effort whatsoever to make a ceasefire in that conflict.

The US' objection would be that, while the plight of the innocent civilians in Gaza is extremely unfortunate, there are a few problems:

1. Cease fires with Hamas don't work - there was a ceasefire on October 6th from the last conflict, Hamas broke it on October 7th. And its not nearly the first time they've broken ceasefires. A ceasefire is merely kicking the can down the road, except down the road the can will kill and kidnap civilians, and present a constant existential security threat.
2. There is no other country in the world that is held up to the absurd standards that Israel is - when the governing body of a land mass attacks its neighbour, unfortunately the residents suffer - especially when said governing body embeds terrorists in civilian areas as a strategy. So the fact that the Palestinian people are suffering has no bearing on the fact that Hamas is a terrorist organization that needs to be destroyed.

Sources (they are all copied to highlight, so it will take you to the correct paragraph):

- [https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2023/11/04/background-press-call-by-senior-administration-officials-on-israel-and-gaza/](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2023/11/04/background-press-call-by-senior-administration-officials-on-israel-and-gaza/#:%7E:text=SENIOR%20ADMINISTRATION%20OFFICIAL%3A%20Thanks%2C%20M,know%2C%20where%20people%20should%20move.)
- [https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2023/11/04/background-press-call-by-senior-administration-officials-on-israel-and-gaza/](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2023/11/04/background-press-call-by-senior-administration-officials-on-israel-and-gaza/#:%7E:text=But%20a%20ceasefire%2C%20I%20think%2C%20depends%20on%20the%20Israelis%20feeling%20secure%20and%20ensuring%20that%20something%20like%20this%20cannot%20happen%20again.)
- [https://www.state.gov/briefings/department-press-briefing-december-6-2023/](https://www.state.gov/briefings/department-press-briefing-december-6-2023/#:%7E:text=MR%20MILLER%3A%20So%20I%20will%20not,to%20carry%20out%20terrorist%20attacks%20against%20Israel.)
- [https://www.state.gov/secretary-antony-j-blinken-with-jake-tapper-of-cnn-state-of-the-union-3/](https://www.state.gov/secretary-antony-j-blinken-with-jake-tapper-of-cnn-state-of-the-union-3/#:%7E:text=We%20want%20to,from%20happening%20again.)
- [https://www.state.gov/secretary-antony-j-blinken-at-a-press-availability-41/](https://www.state.gov/secretary-antony-j-blinken-at-a-press-availability-41/#:%7E:text=But%20as%20I,again%20and%20again.)
- [https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/speeches-remarks/2023/11/09/remarks-by-president-biden-before-marine-one-departure-39/](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/speeches-remarks/2023/11/09/remarks-by-president-biden-before-marine-one-departure-39/#:%7E:text=Q%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%20(Inaudible)%20Gaza%20ceasefire%2C%20Mr.%20President%3F%0A%C2%A0%0ATHE%20PRESIDENT%3A%C2%A0%20Pardon%20me%3F%0A%C2%A0%0AQ%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%20What%20are%20the%20chances%20of%20a%20Gaza%20ceasefire%3F%C2%A0%0A%C2%A0%0ATHE%20PRESIDENT%3A%C2%A0%20None.%C2%A0%20No%20possibility.)
- [https://usun.usmission.gov/explanation-of-vote-on-a-united-arab-emirates-drafted-un-security-council-resolution-on-the-situation-in-the-middle-east/](https://usun.usmission.gov/explanation-of-vote-on-a-united-arab-emirates-drafted-un-security-council-resolution-on-the-situation-in-the-middle-east/#:%7E:text=Perhaps%20most%20unrealistically%2C%20this%20resolution%20retains%20a%20call%20for%20an%20unconditional%20ceasefire.%20I%20explained%20in%20my%20remarks%20this%20morning%20why%20this%20is%20not%20only%20unrealistic%20but%20dangerous%3A%20it%20would%20simply%20leave%20Hamas%20in%20place%2C%20able%20to%20regroup%20and%20repeat%20what%20it%20did%20on%20October%207.)
- [https://usun.usmission.gov/explanation-of-vote-on-a-united-arab-emirates-drafted-un-security-council-resolution-on-the-situation-in-the-middle-east/](https://usun.usmission.gov/explanation-of-vote-on-a-united-arab-emirates-drafted-un-security-council-resolution-on-the-situation-in-the-middle-east/#:%7E:text=As%20long%20as,the%20next%20war.)
- [https://academic.oup.com/book/9859/chapter-abstract/157134577](https://academic.oup.com/book/9859/chapter-abstract/157134577?redirectedFrom=fulltext#:%7E:text=Between%20300%2C000%E2%80%93600%2C000%20German%20civilians%20and%20over%20200%2C000%20Japanese%20civilians%20were%20killed%20by%20allied%20bombing%20during%20the%20Second%20World%20War%2C%20most%20as%20a%20result%20of%20raids%20intentionally%20targeted%20against%20civilians%20themselves.)
- [https://watson.brown.edu/costsofwar/costs/human/civilians/afghan](https://watson.brown.edu/costsofwar/costs/human/civilians/afghan#:%7E:text=As%20of%20March%202023%2C%20more%20than%2070%2C000%20Afghan%20and%20Pakistani%20civilians%20are%20estimated%20to%20have%20died%20as%20a%20direct%20result%20of%20the%20war.)
- [https://www.britannica.com/event/Iran-Iraq-War] [11]
- [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10171164/] [12]
- https://www.statista.com/statistics/1293492/ukraine-war-casualties [13]

[11]: [https://www.britannica.com/event/Iran-Iraq-War#:~:text=The%20number%20of,see%20Kurd](https://www.britannica.com/event/Iran-Iraq-War#:%7E:text=The%20number%20of,see%20Kurd)).
[12]: [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10171164/#:~:text=We%20estimate%20that,related%20to%20combat](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10171164/#:%7E:text=We%20estimate%20that,related%20to%20combat).

Comment: In 8 days of cease-fire, based on indirect Israel-Hamas negotiations, 105 hostages were released.  In two months of bombings, one hostage was liberated.  Now which strategy would make more sense to continue if hostages were a priority?

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question with quotes from US officials?  As it stands now, it's not clear whether you are expressing your own opinion or the opinion of the USA.  Did US officials state points (1) and (2) in your answer?

Comment: @gerrit Sure, I can add sources in.

Comment: @gerrit Done...

Comment: @gerrit, unfortunately, hostages released is not a barometer of peace. Hostages (3 month old babies!? 4 yr old girls who are still talking in a whisper?!) are a barbaric tool of Hamas to ensure Israel doesn't dismantle their power structures and kill their leaders. Peace however would be described as ensuring Hamas can't use Oct. 7 as a "rehearsal" for more (-Sinwar). To that end a ceasefire is completely counterproductive.

Comment: @gerrit Israel claims that the negotiations were successful in part because of the pressure their military action has put on Hamas. This may or may not be the case, but negotiations and military action are not entirely independent of each other.

Comment: @gerrit Hostages are not and must not be the priority, because that gives undeserved *de facto* legitimacy to hostage-takers and provides bad actors with incentives to take more hostages.  The first priority, above all else, must be *Hamas delenda est.*

Answer (score 1):

While @Tom is correct, in that the veto is part of the US' ongoing support for Israel, it is not true that UNSC votes are made with the matter at hand being an aftertought. More often than not the matters are quite grave, and occupy the "thought" of many UN and UNSC members, especially the larger empires, all the time when they come up in the UNSC.

The same is true for the Israeli onslaught in Gaza. This matter occupies quite a hefty chunk of public discourse and the news cycle in the US these days - perhaps even more than the war in Ukraine. The administration is under pressure from multiple sides and even internally - to support Israel more staunchly or to use the US' leverage to stop the killing, let humanitarian aid through, withdraw ground troops etc.

Biden has opted for full support of Israel for the past two months, while signaling that the US would like the operation concluded within a few weeks. He has also backed this up with a statement of intent to [bankroll the affair to the tune of 14 Billion USD](https://www.timesofisrael.com/biden-asks-congress-to-okay-14-billion-in-aid-to-israel-61-billion-for-ukraine/).

All of this happened with a humanitarian situation which was already untenable in Gaza *before* the current Israeli campaign: The siege blocking most trade and transport of goods, the water beginning to salinate, lack of electricity during much of the day etc. And - what OP describes in their first two bullets is the obvious consequence of a massive bombing campaign. So, **the US vetoed the cease-fire resolution because it wants the Israeli campaign in Gaza to continue,** or at the very least - prefers its continuation to an argument with Israel and the 'Israel lobby' over the matter.

That being said - OP is overly emphasizing the ties of US-hostile or Israel-hostile armed groups, and IMHO is getting carried away talking about a regional war widening into a third world war. Despite some Yemenis firing some rockets, so far this does not seem to be in the cards. Or at least - many don't see it talkingso, and possibly so does the USA.

Comment: Very important point that Biden is under pressure to do something against the human rights violations by the current Israel military campaign. His public image is all the more important because the American election campaigns are slowly getting under way. If the left discontent with Biden grows he may face a primary challenger. American support for Israel is a confluence of a multitude of reasons, but it is not unlimited.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: A primary challenger is not his main problem. The DNC cancelled the primary debates and the mainstream media refuses exposure to the main challengers - Kennedy and Williamson, with ~20% and 10% respectively a few months ago already. Kennedy decided it's rigged and went off to be an independent candidate; Williamson is sticking with it, but has no chance. Plus, the Florida party completely _cancelled_ the primaries and just put Biden forward as the state delegation's choice for the convention. However,

Comment: Biden has three more serious problems. The first is his health and cognitive capacity, but that's not policy related. The second is _independent candidates_. RFK, Cornell West and Jill Stein are "covering" both his left flank and his, shall we say, traditionalist/liberal-ish non-left flank, meaning he would need to try to pander to these parts of the electorate and can't use the "It's me or Trump!" line as well. Even worse, disaffected left-leaning, Arab, and Muslim voters are more likely to stay home and not come out for "Genocide Joe".

Comment: I also realized after writing this that the time for a primary challenge has already passed, even legally in a few states. (But there is actually a significant chance that he dies before the election.) Yes, losing (even more of the) the left-leaning young voters would be fatal, judging by the current polls.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Well, you know, Trump's legal trouble might catch up to him before the elections I suppose. Plus - the polls typically focus on the popular vote percentages, which as we know, don't mean all that much.